# Fail to extract the gender information from the first name in R

Tags: r

I attempted to extract gender information from the first name using  **gender** package in R. I tried both 'ssa' and 'genderize' for argument **method**.

Here is my demo sample code.

```
unique_id <- seq(0:6)
first_name <- c("annie j", "Juan", "Richard", "Aj",
                "Dana", "annie j", "liyuan")

demo1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(unique_id, first_name))
```

For **ssa**, it uses names based from the U.S. Social Security Administration baby name data. Therefore, if the name does not include in **ssa**, it will return the error as shown below.

```
demo1$gender <- gender(demo1$first_name, method="ssa")$gender
```

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, gender, value = c("male", "female",  :
> replacement has 4 rows, data has 7

I know this is because 'annie j' is not included in the name dataset, `ssa`. Any suggestions or advice to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trim all characters after the first space in the string:

```r
gender(gsub(" .*", "", first_name), method = "ssa")
```

```
 name    proportion_male proportion_female gender year_min year_max
  <chr>             <dbl>             <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Aj               0.988             0.0119 male       1932     2012
2 annie            0.0053            0.995  female     1932     2012
3 annie            0.0053            0.995  female     1932     2012
4 Dana             0.202             0.798  female     1932     2012
5 Juan             0.992             0.0084 male       1932     2012
6 Richard          0.996             0.0037 male       1932     2012
```

(If you prefer tidyverse you could use `stringr::str_remove()` or `stringr::str_extract()` instead)

Note that `liyuan` is still missing.  You might want something like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
demo2 <-  demo1 |> 
  mutate(trim_name = stringr::str_remove(first_name, " .*"))
namedat <- gender(unique(demo2$trim_name), method = "ssa") |>
     select(trim_name = name, gender)
demo3 <- left_join(demo2, namedat, by = "trim_name") |>
     select(-trim_name)
```

```
  unique_id first_name gender
1         1    annie j female
2         2       Juan   male
3         3    Richard   male
4         4         Aj   male
5         5       Dana female
6         6    annie j female
7         7     liyuan   <NA>
```

Comment: `str_trim` will remove whitespace: it won't remove characters *after* whitespace ...

Comment: Really appreciate your kind help. It helps me out